# Solving differential equation (equation whose unknown is a function)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I had homework asked us to solve a differential equation

I did it myself but now I'm stuck  i found: $$\int\frac1ydy=6x$$

How can I continue?

Comment: Hi - could you describe what you have already tried? You will get a much better response if people now you have already tried something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\rm\int\dfrac 1t\,\mathrm dt=\ln|\,t\,|+C\quad\color{grey}{ \text{ and }}\quad e^{\displaystyle\ln x\,}=x$$

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Answer (score 1):

You should have got this:
$$\int \dfrac {1}{y}=6x$$

Knowing that $$\int \dfrac {1}{x}=\ln x+c_1$$ you can get:
$$\int \dfrac{1}{y} dy=6x \implies \ln y=6x+c$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac1ydy=ln|y|+c=6x$,

 therefore $e^{ln|y|+c}=e^{6x}$,

 or $|y|e^c=e^{6x}$

 or $|y|=e^{6x}e^c$ (we write $e^{-c}$ as $e^{c}$ since both $-c$ and $c$ represent an arbitrary constant.)

 or $y=\pm e^ce^{6x}$ (for example if $|x|=1$, then $x=\pm 1$)

 or $y=Ae^{6x}$ where $A\in \mathbb R$ is determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: No, I'm teaching